# Replace text after a string with powershell

Tags: regex, string, powershell, teamcity

Hi all im working on a build script using powershell to replace some cacheBuster values with the build number.

Ive got replacing a basic string with the build number working fine. However when the file is not updated it is not brought down clean from svn, so my matching parameter is no longer valid.

So far my code is this

**The JS FILE**

```
 "deps": ["app"],
    "name": "app",
    "urlArgs": "bust=",
    "waitSeconds"  : 60,
    "catchError": {
        "define": true
    }
```

**The Powershell Script**

```
$path = "jsmin\config.js"
$word = "bust="
$replacement = $build
$text = get-content $path 
$newText = $text -replace $word,$replacement
$newText > $path
```

What I want to do to solve this problem is look for a variable like bust=buildnumber and then just replace all text after bust= with the buildNumber. Im assuming i need a regex to do this but not quiet sure how.

Any help would be great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```
$path = "jsmin\config.js"
$word = "bust="
$text = Get-Content $path 
$text -replace ("(?<=$word)" +'(.*?)(?=")'), $build | Set-Content $path
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, thats close it does replace the correct area, but after it adds the build it wipes the rest of the file after bust=292929

Comment: It had a bug as it removed the last `",` but if it erases the rest of your text, then your js file is single line and not multi-line like your sample is. Try updated answer

Comment: Yep that was exactly the problem i was running on the minifed files. Your new code works great thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A possible alternative. If you are using a version of PowerShell that has Convert[To|From]-Json, you can convert the Json to a PowerShell Object, get the property names, check the values, update the target and convert the PS Object back to Json.

More verbose and slower than a regex but an option.

```
$build=(Get-Date).ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss")

$js = @"
{
 "deps": ["app"],
    "name": "app",
    "urlArgs": "bust=",
    "waitSeconds"  : 60,
    "catchError": {
        "define": true
    }
}
"@ | ConvertFrom-Json 

$pn = ($js | Get-Member -MemberType *Property).Name

$pn | % {
    if($js.$PSItem -match "^bust=") 
    {
        $js.$PSItem="bust=$build"
    }
}

$js | ConvertTo-Json # > "config.js"
```